# Change the order of bibliographystyle unsrt

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, moderncv

In the `moderncv`, I wanted to add my publications. I have chosen bibliographystyle `unsrt`. It looks great but the only problem is, it ordering from old publications to the new one. Is there anyway to change the order of it, and make it from *new* publications to *old* one.
If I can use  another bibliographystyle with ordering from new papers to old one, also can be good.

Thank you so much

```
\section{Pulications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystylearticle{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{publications.bib}
```

Comment: The main characteristic of the `unsrt` bibliography style is that *it applies no sorting*, alphabetical or otherwise. Hence, the ordering of the bib entries corresponds exactly to the ordering of their first citation in the body of the document. If you want a different ordering in the bibliography, you will need to change the ordering of the citation call-outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your given code snippet you used `\nocite{*}`.  I suppose you do not have any `\cite{}`s in code.  Then you get the bibliography sorted after the order of the bib file. Sort by your own your bib file to get the youngest documents printed first, the oldest printet last.

The following MWE shows you a bib file (ordered from new to old) and the tex code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystylearticle{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

Please see that I commented your not needed line `\bibliographystylearticle{apacite}`.

The MWE results in the following page:

[image]

If you want another order of the bib entrys change the order in the bib file ...